# Are review audits supposed to be only for the tags that you filtered

Tags: support, tags, review-queues, review-audits

I have a filter set to [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) set for the review items. However I have been given questions to review that aren't tagged with any of these tags. Is this a bug or done on purpose?

[image]

Comment: I just came to ask this as well. I have my filter set for [tag:C#], and received a review for something on [tag:Haskell].

Comment: possible duplicate of [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug)

Comment: I added an example screenshot and removed the possible duplicates, as this question has been cited as the close as duplicate reason for a number of newer questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, review audits will not always show questions from the tags you selected. Remember, the purpose of audits are to see if you're paying attention and reviewing correctly. If you see a question that doesn't look like it even belongs to the tags you're filtering on, it's a good sign that you've hit a review audit. If you notice this, you were paying attention. I always cheat and open the question in a new tab when I hit upon one of these, just to see if it's a review audit or if it's a question that's been mis-tagged.

Comment: "I always cheat and open the question in a new tab" - I take offense to the gaming of the system. Its not intended to be cheated. (With all due respect).

Comment: @jww Yes it is. Why do you think there's a link to the post? If you suspect something's not right with the review, you've already proven that you're paying attention. Audit passed.

Comment: Gaming or cheating the system is not mentioned at [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work). Perhaps some language needs to be added to promote the practice.

Comment: @jww I think Bill's point is that examining the question in more detail isn't really cheating or gaming the system, as it's a practice that leads to *better* reviews.  Because the review interface (for audit and non-audit tasks) doesn't show all the relevant context, it's a **good** practice to open the question in a new window or tab.  As Bill mentioned, it might be a legitimate review for a question that was mistagged. If the audits are encouraging behavior like this, then they have a beneficial effect.

Comment: I quite often open questions in a new tab, just to figure out what the heck is going on.