# Why do audits include ignored tag questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-audits

I just received this review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6296394

The audit is disguising the question as being from one of my filtered preferred tags. OK, [this has been discussed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266876/are-review-audits-supposed-to-be-only-for-the-tags-that-you-filtered/266877#266877) and apparently merely spotting that the question is nothing to do with the tag is good enough to pass.

In this case though, the question's real tags include one on my ignore list (android). By ignoring the tag, I have specifically told the system that I am not capable of, or interested in, providing an opinion on these questions; by rights the *only* thing I should be doing is Skipping it.

I get that "if you can tell that it's an audit, you already passed"; but if my most likely action is to Skip based on the content, surely the audit is of no use anyway? (Particularly in the case of this question... I honestly don't know what the audit expects me to do anyway. Which leads back to one reason I ignored the tag!)

Shouldn't audits take ignored tags into account?

Comment: `...surely the audit is of no use anyway?` Audits aren't really designed to **test** you.  They are there to catch users who robotically click "Looks OK" without paying attention.  So there is little use in the audit itself once you identified it as such.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've identified it as an audit, good job. You are clearly paying attention. Now, it's up to you whether you take the proper action, or just skip it, knowing that it's worked.

So, I don't think it's necessary to exclude them.