# The buttons in review audit are misplaced

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-proposals

This [proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/149413) is looking like this:

[image: Like this]

The buttons are a little bit on the wrong side for some reason.

Comment: That's because it's an audit. For normal reviews they're on the right.

Comment: @Floern Yes, I passed it and therefore I figured out it's an audit. But it's not right. Everybody then can distinguish audits and reviews. Also it looks strange.

Comment: Yeah, even in an audit they should be lined up correctly. This is definitely a bug.

Comment: You found a thing in an audit that was actually acknowledged to be a bug. All anyone else ever gets is, "Congratulations, you spotted an audit". I'm surprised and kind of impressed.

Comment: Is that the plugin to automatically detect audits? ;)

Comment: Ha! No more failed audits! /s

Comment: I've also noticed that issue. Similar to First Post queue, when **after applying a filter you can easily spot the audits** :) However, I think I totally agree [with the statement in this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266876/are-review-audits-supposed-to-be-only-for-the-tags-that-you-filtered) -  _"[...] the purpose of audits are to see if you're paying attention and reviewing correctly. If you see a question that doesn't look like it even belongs to the tags you're filtering on, it's a good sign that you've hit a review audit."_

Comment: i have never seen the buttons on the left, i must be incredibly lucky to not get audits

Comment: @WhatsThePoint The buttons were placed in the right spot earlier

Comment: @sudo how strange