# Audit for First Posts Queue with filtered tag, but then the tag disappeared

Tags: support, tags, review-queues, review-audits, first-post-review

Today I failed reviewing an Audit Post from the First Posts Queue

> STOP! Look and Listen. This was an audit, designed to see if you were
>   paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This
>   was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it
>   as-is or even upvoting. Don't worry, we've already handled this post
>   appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely,
>   keeping in mind the guidance above.

I filtered by the tag `python`, so it only displays related posts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26001273) audit post had several tags (including `python`), but it seemed unrelated to me, so I tried to leave a comment asking for the relationship with that tag. I was going to skip the review after commenting as I did not find the post wrong (just maybe misstagged), but I didn't have the chance as I "failed" the audit instantly.

When I looked again at the tags, `python` **was not there anymore**, even not in the edit history. Am I missing something?

I found [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266876/are-review-audits-supposed-to-be-only-for-the-tags-that-you-filtered) related, but **I am 100% sure** I saw that tag. And if [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345988/12882660) answer is true, then it should not fail your review by doing a comment, should it?

Comment: Related: [Review audit failed after just clicking add comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify tag filtering that shouldn't be a way to sidestep all audits. The system therefore [adds one of the tags you're filtering on to the audit post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204645/188189) in order to make it a tiny bit harder to spot the audit.

That works reasonably well for bad audits i.e. audits of bad posts, you can still downvote them, vote to close them or do some other reasonable action. It works less well for known good post audits as they now have an unexpected tag and are seeing a question that's unrelated to what you'd normally expect. You just have to watch out for good posts with one bad tag and deal with them accordingly now you know they may well be audits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the system is mistaken then, as a mistagged post (no matter how good it is) should be editted to remove that tag. If there are no python related posts to be audits, then show me another unrelated post without that tag to see if I'm paying attention, but **do not lie** making up tags.

Comment: It is 2023 now and the behaviour is STILL THERE. Indeed, faking a tag just so I can get an extra test seems is biasing us towards fail.

Comment: @OCa Not showing you any audits because there aren't any in your obscure tag filters seems biasing you towards you not doing it properly because you're never audited.

Comment: @RobertLongson I understand and support the idea of tests. The point is about the system cheating at them. Surely it could make up more tests for the tag I feel confident in reviewing? Or are those in short supply because manually crafted in some obscure office? ;) I am a 500-rep noob and just beginning to notice the cracks on the ceiling.