# Answer Audits Appearing Even Though I set the Filter to be Questions Only

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, review-suspension

I was recently suspended from review because the system says I failed three audits. When I was reviewing, I set the filter to be "Questions Only" (as shown below) but answer audits keep appearing in the review queue. Since I set the filter to be questions only, I treated all posts I see as questions. Since very good answers are always inappropriate questions, I got tripped up by the answer audits multiple times.
[image: Filter]

Here are the audits that I failed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28643762
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28659768
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28652232

For the first audit that I failed, since I was just getting used to the reviewing environment, I did make an inappropriate judgment. However, for the second and third ones, I think I voted down for both because I applied the questions filter and thought they were all inappropriate questions.

Is this a system bug that audits for answers are appearing in the questions queue? If so, what's the reason behind it? If not, do I qualify for a suspension lift?

Also, why is this message shown for good posts? It is **misleading**.(As you can see for the second/third posts) If it is intended to draw the reviewer's attention, I would suggest changing a message instead of saying it's "identified as potential spam".
[image: Spam for a good post]

Comment: Well, had you been paying attention you would have noticed the giant text saying "Review the following answer"....

Comment: I usually look at the texts only so it's much more efficient. Since I also applied the filter "Questions Only" so I expected all posts to be questions.

Comment: Looking at external details (such as opening the post in a new tab, looking at the answers to the questions, etc.) is a _huge_ part of reviewing, as that can reveal whether or not a post is an audit. I find it hard to believe anyone can miss such a big text field...

Comment: Quite simple, actually: for the reasons audits also don't respect tag preference. They are ensuring you are paying attention. For the first one, it is clear as day you shouldn't use "no action needed". For the second and third cases, you downvoted 2 ok-ish answers without a second thought something is wrong. I'd say audits did their job perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266876/are-review-audits-supposed-to-be-only-for-the-tags-that-you-filtered

Comment: as @10Rep mentions... you're filtering by questions and the the review says "Review the following **answer**"

Comment: Why would I get an answer review if the filter is only questions though?

Comment: @Parzival - because it is *an audit*. 2/3 times you failed to second-guess yourself: "why am I shown answers instead of questions" and *acted* on them. This is *exactly* one of the cases audits are designed to fish out.

Comment: IMO, the purpose of audits is not to see whether you're paying attention, but to make sure people are giving correct reviews. If that's the case, answer audits shouldn't be given in question queues. If I'm reviewing it as an answers and I intended to review both questions and answer or answers only, I would very likely act appropriately

Comment: That's the thing though... if you don't notice that you're reviewing an answer, rather than a question - the system isn't perfect... it's far from and needs a massive overhaul... but that's neither here nor there

Comment: @Parzival - you acted twice. On answers as if they were questions. I also think the system is not perfect, but come on? If "since I set the filter to be questions only, I treated all posts I see as questions" is not "robo reviewing", I am not sure what is, sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to fix this? I think this will also save reviewers a lot of time too. Reviewers are voluntarily giving their time to this platform, so it's important that they can work efficiently. Could you also look at why good answers are "identified as possible spam" at the bottom of my question?

Comment: [Why did you downvote an answer that had 11 upvotes and directly answered somebody's question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730445/avoid-mutating-props-directly-in-a-nuxt-vuejs/66731178#66731178).  You actually did that [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524645/merge-two-sorted-vectors/66524695#66524695).  It appears you need time away from the review system so you can better understand what is and isn't quality content.  "I got tripped up by the answer audits multiple times." - You got reviewed banned because you not taking the appropriate amount of time to review content

Comment: "Is it possible to fix this?" - There isn't anything to be fixed.  You failed to pay attention.  Seems like the audits literally are working.

Comment: @Parzival (btw, there are @-mentions, use it so as we know who you reply to) we *all are volunteers* here, which doesn't mean we have the right to do a sloppy job. What you keep ignoring in responses to you is that you went ahead and applied a blatantly incorrect action at least 2 times (the first case aside) whether or not you think filters should be respected by audits. This only serves to illustrate that audits did a good job here.

Comment: @SecurityHound People are voluntarily giving their time, and you're saying that there's nothing to fix even though the system can be improved. IMHO the review experience isn't that great for me as a newcomer.

Comment: Here is the thing, bad reviews creates a ton of work for everyone else, so if a user who made some obvious bad review decisions through an audit has to take a break to understand that bad reviews queue choices is a big deal then so be it.  Review queue system isn’t perfect but it does the job, what is and isn’t an audit,  couldn’t be more clear

Comment: @SecurityHound Thanks for the clarification. Looking apart from the first review, do you think I would've made the wrong decision if I knew it was an answer? Well, very likely not. That's what I propose should be fixed. Rather than focusing on "paying attention", it should instead be "making correct reviews"

Comment: @Parzival - None of those reviews are difficult, they were all pretty obviously an audit, and I personally don’t buy your excuse on the first review audit since you had [5 and half pages](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13991219/parzival?tab=activity) reviews.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I'd leave this one open just for the sake of further questions about the issue to be properly closed to this one as a dupe target. The tag filter target is related, but does not have answers addressing question/answer setting, so, I think, it is a bit of a stretch to close against it.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

From my understanding, a system which asks me to review an **answer**, when I request only  **questions**, is a wrong system. When I need to constantly check, whether a system actually gives me what I asked, makes me feel like a **tester** for that system, not like a **user** of it.

When set tags for the filter the review queue, I am ready for review any question under these tags. That is, I am ready even for questions, which **content** (body) has nothing common with their **tags**. (These questions are actually exist.)

Because of that, an audit which gives an utterly bad question with improper tag is perfectly OK: I am ready for such questions and I should be able to classify them properly (at least, skip them as "I don't understand the question because I am not an expert in this area").

But when I set a preference to review only questions, I would expect to see **only questions**. Why the system gives me an **answer**?

Others note, that there is a banner with

> Review the following answer

But why should I read after words "review the following", if I asked the system to give only questions?

Should I constantly check, whether I am still in "close-votes" queue, and not in "Low Quality Posts" one, which has non-trivial meaning of actions?

Should I constantly check (according to the address line) whether I am still review on SO, and not e.g. on Unix&Linux? So when I vote-to-close a question as non-*programming*, the audit could tell me

> You don't paying attention that you are currently reviewing on other SE site!

From my understanding, either

- "Filter by Question" option should be removed, or
- When "Filter by Question" option is enabled, the system should never give an answer,
  even as a part of audit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You elaborated my argument perfectly - I would also add that the purpose of audits should be to ensure people are making the right judgment, rather than paying attention. Giving an answer audit under the questions filter clearly is not a good experience at all for the reviewer.

Answer (score 10):

> When I was reviewing, I set the filter to be "Questions Only" (as shown below) but answer audits keep appearing in the review queue.

So, you had a filter set up that showed you only questions. Therefore it is logical to assume that if an answer showed up in the queue, then it is an audit. [This meta post confirms that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266876/are-review-audits-supposed-to-be-only-for-the-tags-that-you-filtered)

An audit is intended to ***make sure you are paying attention***. The reason for this is because there are way too many robo reviewers in the review queue who spam reviews to get badges.

To quote [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288047/12708583):

> If you are paying enough attention and spending enough time on a review task to figure out that a review is an audit, then the audit has already done its job.

So as soon as you notice a review is an audit, you've essentially passed.

> Since I set the filter to be questions only, I treated all posts I see as questions. Since very good answers are always inappropriate questions, I got tripped up by the answer audits multiple times.

Well, if there was no indication of the post specifically being an answer, I would have been more inclined to support this proposal. However, there is a literal banner which tells you whether a post is an answer or not:

[image]

And not only that, but you made the same mistake ***twice***. The first time you confused an answer for a question, it would make sense to look at the text, or to skip a post which looks like an answer as it may be an audit.

Additionally it's good practice to open any post in a new tab just to get more context and information. For instance, if a post is deleted in a new tab or has a different amount of votes than shown in the queue, then it is indeed an audit.

---

The system occasionally gives you the message that a post may be potential spam. This is just to get you alert of an audit, which again, checks if you are paying attention. Sometimes, it's just best to ignore that, as it is aware of whether the review is an audit or not.

Comment: I agree on the most part, but I disagree about the "potential spam". It's literally *misleading* the reviewer if it's a good post. The reviewer is voluntarily giving time to review, and the message is misleading them in the audit.

Comment: @Parzival - That’s the point of the audit.  You are displayed a message that indicates it’s spam, but it’s actually high quality content, it’s supposed to be obvious and only those who are not paying attention will fail the audit.  It really doesn’t matter the review ban is legitimate, this isn’t a case of a single audit failure, but multiple failures.  You claim [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28643762) was failed as you learned the system but that wasn’t your first review

Comment: @Parzival checking back, I'd say don't be too discouraged by a review ban. It will go away after a few days or so (considering that this is your first one). Many people have been review banned before. It's the least drastic action that can be taken.

Comment: @10Rep Thanks for your response. I am not too discouraged by it, but I will definitely do less, if at all, in the future. It is really not a good experience for me as a reviewer - as I have stated, we should be checking if the reviewer is **making the right judgment** rather than **paying attention**. I think this will appeal to future reviewers as well. As a result, I am giving the accepted answer to Tsyvarev - he makes a very good point that the system which asks me to constantly check what it gives me even though I applied a filter is not a good system at all.

Comment: @Parzival well I disagree with that but it’s fine.

Comment: @Parzival - But you didn’t make the correct decision?  The fact you got a audit for an answer instead of a question doesn’t change that fact.  Why participate less in review queues because of a couple failed audits?

Comment: @SecurityHound I would've made the right decision if the filter had worked correctly. Why participate more in review queues if it actually doesn't give you a good experience at all, such as showing answers while filtering as questions?

Comment: @Parzival - and yet you made the same incorrect choice *twice*. This is also well-known enough that reviewers should make themselves acquainted with. You are playing with words here: the system does not present you with the posts ignoring the filter *unless* this is an audit. What the review queues do not need is people mindlessly following instructions. As was already asked multiple times - did you report the suspicious post, skipped, or double-checked why the answer is suddenly in the queue? No. I am not sure I understand why the review system is in the wrong.

Comment: Should this “bug” be fixed, maybe, but that doesn’t change the fact the incorrect choice was selected three times